# Python: a more concise way to filter a list

Tags: python, filter

I'd like to execute some code for every element in a list that match some property.
So my code would look like:

```
for x in filter(f, lx):
    do some stuff
```

But my function f is defined in the object x, so I have to write:

```
for x in filter(lambda x: x.f(), lx):
    do some stuff
```

Maybe I'm a bit picky, but I find it stupid to define a lambda function when I already define this function somewhere else...
Is there a more efficient and concise way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use directly the `f` method defined in your class:

```
for x in filter(X.f, lx):
    # do some stuff
```

A more efficient way using the `itertools` module to avoid the creation of a new list and use beautiful python generator:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.ifilter(X.f, lx):
    # do some stuff
```

Assumning `X` is the class of element in lx.

Small example:

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self, b):
        self.b
    def check (self):
        return self.b < 10

l = [A(8), A(40), A(5), A(7), A(33)]
for a in filter(A.check, l):
    print a.b
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you know if it is as efficient as the answer of @NedBatchelder ? I'm mean it should be but is python creating a new list on the fly ?

Comment: @user3561471 I think it's a more 'python' aproach than the NedBatchelder one, but it's less efficient (python is creating a list on the fly). I've updated my answer using  the `itertools` module which is (I think) the best option!

Comment: FWIW, I think many people will be surprised that this works.  It's an unusual technique rarely seen used.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I don't know if it's commonly used, but I don't see why it shouldn't be. The doc (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) says that `X.f` is a function taking an instance of `X` for first argument, and that `x.f()` is exactly equivalent to `X.f(x)`, so it's clearly defined by the `doc`. IMO, people are afraid of using class method as callback function because of the way it works in other languages such as C++ where dealing with function method is clearly not as simple as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps avoid filter:

```
for x in lx:
    if x.f():
        # do some stuff
```

It's more lines, but clearer code.  If you find yourself doing it often, make a generator:

```
def filter_f(lx):
    for x in lx:
        if x.f():
            yield x

...

for x in filter_f(lx):
    # do something
```

(this came out longer than you'd like I suspect, but demonstrates another way to do it.)